# graph api to get list of video uploaded on facebook via share dialogue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I need a list of videos uploaded via share dialogue by the user using my app. I can't see any app-specific data added to the video in graph API, however, uploaded videos on Facebook does have the tag of my app when they get added to the feed. I want to track videos uploaded by the user using my app's share dialogue. Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: The share dialog doesn’t allow for _uploading_ of videos, it allows to share external URLs or posts. And your app has no access to what a user shares on their own timeline, unless that specific user logs in to your app and grants it read access first.

Comment: @misorude it does now. Have a look https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android?sdk=fbsdk#prereqs

Comment: Oh you’re talking about the Android version, should have said that, I assumed you meant the web version of the dialog … Doesn’t change the fact though, that to access anything the user shared to their own feed, you would need their individual permission first.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported feature by the Facebook API. So there is no way to get this done without help from the Facebook team.